# How to get properties of a model attribute?

Tags: python, xml, django, serialization

Let's say that I have a class such as :

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    attributeA = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attributeB = models.IntegerField()
    attributeC = models.CharField(max_length = 150, blank=True, nullable = True)
    attributeD = models.ForeignKey('ModelB',related_name='FK_modelB')
    attributeE = models.ManyToManyField('ModelC')
```

What I want to do is to get the properties of every attribute, not just the name that I got with :

```
my_instance._meta.get_all_field_name()
```

(which gave me a list of attributes names). No, what I want is, for every attribute, know what is his type (CharField,IntegerField, ForeignKey, ManyToManyField...), who's related if it's a ForeignKey / ManyToManyField and all the meta data such as max_length and so on.

The aim of it is to serialize a class into a XML and the representation in the XML will be different if it's a ManyToManyField, a ForeignKey or a simple value.

By the way, If anyone know a great class serializer to XML, it would help me a lot !

Thanks for your responses !

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in [serialization framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/serialization/)?

Comment: That's what I did ! I didn't know Django had a good serialization built-in framework :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django models `_meta.fields` is fields list that you can access to get field attributes:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.all()[0]
>>> u._meta.fields[1].__class__.__name__
'CharField'
>>> u._meta.fields[1].name
'username'
>>> u._meta.fields[1].max_length
30
>>> u._meta.fields[1].blank
False
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I searched. I also found an easiest way to do that, using django serializer module
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get attributes of a specific field by using get_field()

MyClass._meta.get_field('attributeA').max_length